# One-liner python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have this function and I would like to make a dictionary in the same way but with just one-liner using lambda expression (most probably)

```
def make_dict():
    y = {}
    for i in range(0, 10, 2):
        y[i] = i+1
        y[i+1] = i
    return y
```

I could not make it, since all lambda expressions that are for a specific pattern and cannot assign the second element in the dictionary with respect to the first one

I could not make it, since all lambda expressions that are for a specific pattern and cannot assign the second element in the dictionary with respect to the first one

I have already tried:

```
 {(i if i%2==0 else i+1) :(i+1 if i%2==0 else i) for i in range(0, 10, 2)}
```

I expect the result to be:

```
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 7, 7: 6, 8: 9, 9: 8}
```

Comment: If you think of it as key + 1 where the key is even and key - 1 where the key is odd, it becomes more straightforward as a comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be using dict-comprehension:

```py
out = {i: i - 1 if i % 2 else i + 1 for i in range(10)}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 7, 7: 6, 8: 9, 9: 8}
```